# What is the easiest way to transmit data from a computer to an FPGA?

Tags: fpga

I have never programmed for a physical interface before. [This](http://www.altera.co.uk/education/univ/materials/boards/de0/unv-de0-board.html) is the board I am currently using, although I do have access to most of the DE boards on the list.

I need to continuously transmit 3 16-bit numbers at 50 Hz from the computer to the board, in one direction. I don't think serial/parallel transmission matters given the frequency. However, I would prefer one that is easier to code.

Comment: Maybe get a USB to RS232 adapter?

Comment: It has an RS232 transceiver, but no port.

Comment: If that particular board has USART hardware you could use a USB to USART bridge.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Considering your request a classic serial interface will do the work perfectly.

**From a HDL perspective a serial transceiver is easy to implement**, so I think you should start from here. Your board has no RS232 connectors, but you can easily use the expansion headers in order to connect a FT232 chip, that convert your serial interface to USB.

With a solution like this from both PC and FPGA you can use a serial interface and the FT232 will manage all the USB stuff, that is not so simple if you are just starting with HDL. In this way you have not to worry about USB and at the same time you are using a modern interface that every PC has, unlike the RS232.

Comment: I just got the DE2 board which does have an RS232 port. Can I use the SerialPort class in C# NET to transmit the data through a USB-to-RS232 cable? I don't have an RS232 port in my computer.

Comment: The USB to RS232 converter is recognised from your PC as a COM port, so you can treat it as a physical serial port and use the SerialPort class.